# How to adjust the x-axis range in an effect plot

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I have my fitted models and wanted to plot the effects via the "effects" package in R (v.3.3.1). Up to this point everything works just fine.

```
     dipt.moi <- lmer(log_dipt ~ stemp + shum + swind + scc + ct + mt + (1|plot)

#Plotting:

        library(effects)
        plot(allEffects(dipt.moi)[1])

#or:

        plot(Effect(focal.predictors = "stemp", dipt.moi)
```

But when i look at my plots, i notice that the x-axis doesn't cover all the range from my data. It just "cuts off" some data at the edges. 
Weird thing is, that this doesn't apply for all my plots, only for some and i can't discover a specific pattern here.

[effect plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sd72.jpg)

notice that my actual data range on stemp is from -2.1 to 2.9

i tried to adjust with:

```
plot(Effect(focal.predictors = "stemp", dipt.moi),xlevels=c(-2.1,2.9))

#and

dlist<-list(L$stemp)
plot(Effect(focal.predictors = "stemp", dipt.moi),xlevels=list(dlist))
```

the plot is plotted but won't change a bit.

This question has been asked in other forums too (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-February/366237.html), but i tried it with the xlevels command (as above), the xlim command, and it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to adjust the x-axis here? Maybe it's not even possible?!

Regards, Lukas.

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data and the code you are using to make your plot. That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Updated it, i hope it will be more understandable now. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a `plot()` problem but due to `allEffects()` calculating from -2 to 2. You can define the range using the argument `xlevels`, but you couldn't give it correctly.

```
library(effects); library(lme4)

dipt.moi <- lmer(log_dipt ~ stemp + shum + swind + scc + ct + mt + (1|plot))

dlist <- list(stemp = seq(-2.1, 2.9, 0.4))       # the example values
plot(allEffects(dipt.moi, xlevels = dlist)[1])
```

Comment: Wow, i really must have missed that. Thank you so much. Worked perfectly for me.